# What is TElement in C# documentation?

Tags: c#

In C# Documentations, there was an example under constructed types where they use class Queue , what is TElement and what does it mean /represent?

Answer (score 0):

It's a placeholder for whatever type you wish to specify.

It could be `Queue<string>` or `Queue<int>` or `Queue<List<int>` or `Queue<SomeComplicatedClass>` - whatever you like.

It's called a "generic type parameter" (the bit between the `<` and the `>`).

The [docs page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.queue-1?view=net-6.0) has the following example:

```
Queue<string> numbers = new Queue<string>();
numbers.Enqueue("one");
numbers.Enqueue("two");
numbers.Enqueue("three");
numbers.Enqueue("four");
numbers.Enqueue("five");
```

You can read more about generic type parameters [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-type-parameters).